# Ignoring a line of HTML from a page cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to ignore a line of HTML (in this case it's JS, but that's irrelevant) from a page cache?

To sum it up, I've got a page being cached using caches_page which in some cases the page is viewed with a parameter which sets off a trigger in JS. More specifically, there's an image viewer in there where the JS trigger is an index for the array of the slideshow. So if the param is there with, say, the value of "6" it'll go to the 6th image in the slideshow rather than starting from the beginning. Pretty straightforward stuff.

I would like to cache this page without the offending line of JS ( imgIndex(#) ). Any way to pull that off? If it makes any difference, and I know it might, I'm on Rails 2, not 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fragments cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html) instead. That way you can leave the JS and anything you want out of the important stuff.

Something like this:

```
# your JS and any content you don't wanna cache goes here or after the following block
<% cache do %>
  <% #anything here will be cached %>
<% end %>
```